# Can't get past 'error: missing braces around initializer'

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, anonymous-struct

Getting the following error when doing the anonymous struct below:

`error: missing braces around initializer [-Werror=missing-braces]`

If I swap 'message' out for a static string like 'lalala', that works fine.

```
typedef struct {
    /* public: */
    char message[255];
} Note;

static uint16_t local_size = 0;
static Note *notes;


Note *add_local_note(const char *_message) {
    //char bla[255] = "hot hot hot";

    notes[(++local_size)-1] = (Note) {
        .message = _message
    };

    return notes;
}
```

Any ideas? And yes I'm new to C, so apologies there.

Comment: There is no declaration of `notes`and no declaration of `local_size` in your program. Could you give a complete test case?

Comment: Removing my vote to close question

Comment: `message` typo as `_message`, and `_message` is pointer. use `strcpy`.

Comment: Updated it with the declarations, and _message was a typo on my part when doing this question. Even when I use bla (commented out) which is a char array, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: can not be initialized with initializer a pointer an array of char. `strcpy(notes[(++local_size)-1].message, _message);`

Comment: BLUEPIXY - that worked! Thanks a bunch. Can you post it as an answer? I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: It would be more conventional to write `notes[local_size++]`.  The larger context still wouldn't work, but that produces the index you want and the increment you want and is idiomatic C.  I'd not seen `(++var)-1` used before, AFAICR — congratulations on inventing that notation (but now forget that you did so).

Comment: Lol yea, that was just a fluke from hours of working on that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is not allow like this

```
char *cp = "sample";    
char carray[10] = cp;//NG, Type is different rather than that is not able to use the variables.

char carray[10] = "sample";// or { "test" };//OK
```

use strcpy (or strncpy)

E.g.

```
strcpy(carray, cp);
```